# How to setup bluetooth network

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, http, wamp

I have installed a BT device on my PC, & I'm connecting my mobile to my PC successfully, but I want to setup my PC & mobile in a such way that my PC will act as http & database server (Apace, Mysql) and my mobile as client.

I've got wamp installed & configured on PC, but I don't know how to view `localhost` on my mobile's browser (i.e. Whenever I'm trying to open `http://localhost/` or 127.0.0.1 it is trying to search on internet not the intranet).

Is it possible to view/browse local http server from mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [GnuBox](http://xan.dnsalias.org/gnubox/), Hiisi or miniBTProxy.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost`/127.0.0.1 is always the *local host*, i.e. the device you're trying to open the URL on. `localhost` on your PC is your PC, `localhost` on your phone is your phone.

If you want to connect to your PC from your phone, use the PC's IP address.